# Is it possible to change number of threads during program execution

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I'm running few openMP programs. Is it possible to change the number of threads during the program execution. For example, if a program takes 70sec to execute using default number of threads, can I change that number say after 30 sec.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can certainly use [omp_set_num_threads()](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fset_005fnum_005fthreads.html) to dynamically change the number of threads each time through your (say) iteration loop, and use that plus timing measurements to adaptively choose the number of cores you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new thread.  A better question you should ask yourself is if multi-threading will benefit you.  Remember, just creating new threads will not speed your program up and in many cases, can actually cause more harm than good (race-conditions, deadlocks etc).  Make sure you have an understanding of how threading works before jumping into it, which judging by your question, you do not.  Threading is a manly task, it puts the hair in your chest, but takes it off of your head!

http://www.inf.uni-konstanz.de/dbis/teaching/ss06/os/ch4.pdf